# How to update from Laravel 5.1 to latest version?

Tags: laravel

Is there an artisan command or other? I am new to Laravel hence the basic question - just looking for some direction with that please.

Seems like it's a mix of automation and testing.

Henry

Comment: There is not an artisan command. If you want to do it yourself, you'll have to go bit by bit - starting with 5.1 --> 5.2, and so on. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade Or, you can use something like https://laravelshift.com/ (paid) to do large portions of it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Composer.json

```
 "require": {

        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",(your deisre version)

    },
```

```
composer install
```

Comment: Laravel has an extensive upgrade guide that needs to be followed. It's far more than a simple bump in the `composer.json` version.